# XSLT: How to convert string value into boolean variable?

Tags: xml, xslt

With XSL 2.0, what's the best way to convert a string value ('true' or 'false') into a boolean variable?

Answer (score 3):

xs:boolean constructor function, e.g. `xs:boolean('true')`